# Redirect all visits to index page

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

I'd like to re-direct all traffic visiting my website (Magento) to an index.html page I have created (this will be temporary for a few days). I guess it would work in much the same way as the maintenance page. Can anyone suggest the best way to do this (limiting the damage to SEO)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats easy. 
Got to you system->configuration
then go to General->design

Then inside HTML head you can put this code in Miscellaneous Scripts field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html"
//-->
</script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to put site to maintenance mode you should create empty maintenance.flag file and upload it to the root folder.
2. Please note that even admin user can not access the site. In order to have access you should modify index.php file in Magento root folder and specify list of IPs that will have access to your site. Download and open original index.php file.
   On line 47 put the following code:

   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; $allowed = array('69.65.23.100','2.2.2.2');

In the `$allowed = array(‘69.65.23.100′,’2.2.2.2′);` you should specify list of IPs that will have access to your site.

3. Search the following code:

   if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {

Replace it with

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
```

4. Refresh your site. It should show up in case you put correct IP address.
5. In order to modify content of maintenance page you should edit `errors/default/503.phtml` file.

Answer (score 0):

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {